# ValueError: [TypeError("'numpy.int32' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, fastapi, logistic-regression

I'm running my LogicRegression model using FastApi locally(127.0.0.1). Then it occurred ValueError just like this:
`ValueError: [TypeError("'numpy.int32' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]`
And server response is:
`500 Undocumented Error:Internal Server Error`

But everything goes well when I run the code locally without FastApi.

```py
@app.put("/senti/{comment}")
def getSentiment(comment: str):
    comment = comment.lower().strip()
    X = getD2Vfeature(comment)
    y = getSentiPolarity(X)
    print(y)
    return {"senti polarity":y}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # goes well when running here
    comment = """
    great... lets work to get this in soon before the codebase changes again...
    """
    getSentiment(comment)
```

And getSentiPolarity() is below:

```py
def getSentiPolarity(X):
    model = joblib.load('source/logicregression_liwc123_d2v.pkl')
    y = model.predict([X])
    return y[0]
```

Is there something wrong in `y=model.predict([X])`?

Comment: Please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message including a stack trace, by copying and pasting, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` until the end, and formatting it as code. Try to create a [mre], and make sure the error corresponds to that code. We should be able to **copy and paste** the code, without changing anything, and *directly* see the *exact* problem described.

Comment: Thank you! I already know what went wrong. In function `getSentiment()` there is a line:   `return {"senti polarity":y}`,   `type(y)` is `<class 'numpy.int32'>`  while fastapi cannot support this type. Just change this line into    `return {"senti polarity":int(y)} `   can solve this error.

Comment: Code formatting does not work properly in comments. If the problem is caused by a typo, then it is not suitable for the site. If the problem is that something needs to be returned, then think more carefully about the requirements. For example, is the **actual** question "how do I convert from `numpy.int32` to a native Python int?" If so, then look for an existing question like that, and otherwise ask.

Answer (score 2):

Fast API does not support `numpy.*` datatypes. You can convert to native python types by calling the NumPy `val.item()` function. Therefore, for the problem above, you could have done `return y[0].item()` and it would have worked.